# I want to draw a rectangle with a touch in UWP

Tags: uwp, touch

The touch start coordinates are the start coordinates of the rectangle.
The touch end coordinate is the end coordinate of the rectangle.

In WPF or Silverlight, it's simple to get mouse events.
UWP is difficult because it does not know touch start coordinates and moving coordinates and end coordinates.

What should I do?

Comment: What have you tried? There are couple of ways to do it - you may user *Pointer* events, *Manipulation* ones will also do a job. You may create Rectangle, use paths, use Win2D or take a look at [InkCanvas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.inkcanvas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UWP, we don't use separate mouse/touch events. We use pointers and there's a type definition to each (pen/touch/mouse). Take a look at `PointerPressed` and `PointerReleased` events. [You can get started here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/handle-pointer-input).